# PHP - Using a drop down list to change site theme

Tags: php, css, forms, drop-down-menu, cookies

I have a drop down list where users can select a theme for the site.  The only problem is, I'm not quite sure how to properly load the theme once they press "Apply".  I am new to PHP.  I know if I use GET, it will pass the variables through a the current page and add them to the end of the URL.  I would really like to avoid that. So, I guess my question is, how can I avoid using GET to update the theme? Thank you.

Here is my code to load the correct theme:

```
<?php
$stylesArr = array('Default', 'Black', 'Pink', 'Green', 'Red');
if(isset($_GET['theme']) && in_array($_GET['theme'], $stylesArr)) {
    $style = $_GET['theme'];
    setcookie("theme", $style, time()+(60*60*24*30));
} else {
    if(isset($_COOKIE['theme']) && in_array($_COOKIE['theme'], $stylesArr)) {
        $style = 'CSS/' . $_COOKIE['theme'] . '.css';
    } else {
        $style = 'CSS/Default.css';
    }
}
?>
```

Here is my drop down list to select the theme:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] ?>" method="post">
<p>Site Theme:
<select name="theme">
<option value="Default">Default</option>
<option value="Black">Black</option>
<option value="Pink">Pink</option>
<option value="Green">Green</option>
<option value="Red">Red</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Apply" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swap $_GET for $_POST. And if it were me i would either post to a separate file e.g theme_manager.php then store it in a session or cookie, then reload the other page

```
header("Location: xxxxx.php");
exit(); # exit is important as page needs to exit and reload for cookie to work.
```

Hope that helps!

here is what you need:

choose_style.php

```
<?
$stylesArr = array('Default', 'Black', 'Pink', 'Green', 'Red');
if(isset($_COOKIE['theme']) && in_array($_COOKIE['theme'], $stylesArr)) {
    $style = 'CSS/' . $_COOKIE['theme'] . '.css';
} else {
    $style = 'CSS/Default.css';
}
?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<? echo $style; ?>">

## drop down code with form posting to theme_switch.php
```

#### theme_switch.php

```
<?
$stylesArr = array('Default', 'Black', 'Pink', 'Green', 'Red');
if(isset($_POST['theme']) && in_array($_POST['theme'], $stylesArr)) {
    $style = $_POST['theme'];
    setcookie("theme", $style, time()+(60*60*24*30));
}

header("Location: choose_style.php"); # this will reload your theme selector
exit(); # this will make sure the cookie gets loaded next time.

?>
```

Comment: Ok, I was just going to ask why when I hit "Apply", it loads the page without any theme.  Will header("Location: xxxxx.php"); exit(); fix this problem?

Comment: Yeah, the cookie only gets read on the next page load! good luck

Comment: Where exactly would I put header("Location: xxxxx.php"); exit();?

Comment: You would need to put that after all you code before the closing ?>

Comment: The only problem is, after the user selects the theme, I would like it to display the page they were on with the updated theme.

Comment: Thats no problem. replace xxxx.php with the filename where the dropdown is and it will simply reload that page after setting the cookie. I will edit my answer with the code you need.

Comment: Hmmm, guess I should've pointed out how the page is setup.  There is "Index.php", which is the main page.  Within that I have have navigation menu and the theme selector is right below that.  The navigation menu and theme selector are located in "Navigation.php".  (I used <?php include("Navigation.php"); ?>).  So I'm not sure if I should automatically redirect the browser back to the previous page from "theme_switch.php".

Comment: Ok, I got it.  I just replaced header("Location: choose_style.php"); with header("Location:".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']."");  Thank you so much for your help.  I really appreciate it.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You are using POST as the method for your form, not GET, thus nothing will be appended to the url, just change all $_GET to $_POST in your php code.

Answer (score 1):

Well, method="post" is the right step, I guess.

The PHP code you got there makes my alarm bells go off, however. You must not trust user input from $_GET, $_POST, $_COOKIE etc.! Never!

So what I would suggest is:

- Use $_POST to get the data from the submitted form
- Make a PHP array with all valid themes, like this:
     $valid_themes = array('Default', 'Black', 'Pink', 'Green', 'Red');
- Before you setcookie() or do anything else with $style or $_COOKIE['theme'] or $_POST['theme'], use http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php to check if the submitted theme name is in your array of valid themes.

Without these security measures, your site will be open to XSS attacks: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting

Comment: The PHP array I'm currently using does have all of the valid themes.  I might sound really dumb, but I'm very new to PHP.  How would I go about using in_array to check if it's a valid theme?

Comment: Ah jesus, you *are* already checking that. I didn't read properly. So never mind the alarm bells comment, it's fine. Sorry. Just use $_POST instead of $_GET and you should be set. :-)

Answer (score 0):

do a `POST` to a page (let's say themeswitcher.php).

There you read the theme the user selected with `$_POST["theme"]`
but the theme in the session (or perhaps even in the database)

and then direct the user back to where he came from by using

```
header("Location: xxxxx.php"); 
exit();
```