# PHP + CSS > Change image style from admin control panel using drop down list

Tags: php, css, drop-down-menu, panel, admin

I have an image displaying on my website homepage, and I need to place another smaller image over part of it (actualy a discount sticker [like this](http://b.dryicons.com/files/graphics_previews/sale_stickers.jpg)).

This is easily implemented with CSS, but the catch here is: I want to implement a drop down list on the admin control panel to choose between different images (witch will have different collors) or no image at all. It's a simple PHP website, not Wordpress.

Looking for it on Google I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388210/php-using-a-drop-down-list-to-change-site-theme) about using a drop down list to change a page's theme. I think the principle is quite the same, but I'm not able to figure out a solution that suits me.

I'm just looking for someone that point me the right directions to look for, because when I try to search Google for it, I always see pages like "How do I css style a dropdownlist/select?"... I appreciate anyone willing to help.

Comment: How are you storing the setting from the admin panel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example (mostly logic)

**1** - You can store your image-names in separate database table

table: **discount_stickers**

```
+----------+---------------------+
| image_id | image_file          |
+----------+---------------------+
|        1 | sticker_red.jpg     |
|        2 | sticker_blue.jpg    |
|        3 | sticker_orange.jpg  |
|        4 | sticker_maroon.jpg  |
|        5 | sticker_brown.jpg   |
|        6 | sticker_green.jpg   |
|        7 | sticker_rainbow.jpg |
+----------+---------------------+
```

**2** - In table where you keep settings for your web-application add new row

table: **app_settings**

```
+------------+---------------------+
| setting    | value               |
+------------+---------------------+
...
| STICKER_ID | 0                   |
+------------+---------------------+
```

Value 0 means no sticker, value greater than zero means **ID** of selected image from table **discount_stickers** (column: `image_id`).

This row in table **app_settings** keeps your choice.

**3** - Generate dropdown box of **discount_stickers** table's elements.

```
$dropdown_code = '<select name="discount_image_picker"><option value="0">No sticker image</option>';

$sql = "SELECT * FROM discount_stickers";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
  $dropdown_code .= '<option value="' . $row['image_id'] . '">' . $row['image_file'] . '</option>';
  }
$dropdown_code .= '</select>';
```

Then echo your `$dropdown_code` where you want in admin panel (in form).

You'll have something like this (according to my example)

[image]

**4** - Now write submit script to store SELECTs value to your database (table **app_settings**, row where `setting=STICKER_ID`). You can use AJAX for update or regular form submit to send request.

**5** - All you need now is to get this value from database when you are about to attach sticker to your images. Use this value to fetch file name from **discount_stickers** table and use that file name to create HTML block with or without sticker (setting style property from PHP code).

**6** - Display new image on your page (put HTML code where you want).

Also, you can use all stickers in one image and store coordinates in database. Later show appropriate part of that image by setting appropriate CSS style parameters.

Of course, also... you can generate output image with (or without) sticker using GD library or ImageMagick. Then you don't need HTML code (DIVs, CSS, etc).

Answer (score 0):

You could hook the change handler on the dropdown like this:

```
<select name="image_chooser" id="image_chooser">
    <option value="image1.gif" selected>Image 1</option>
    <option value="image2.gif">Image 2</option>
</select>

<img src="image1" alt="Image" id="image_to_switch">

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    $("#image_chooser").change(function() {

        $("#image_to_switch").attr("src", $(this).val());

    });

</script>
```

This code assumes you are using jQuery.

Comment: OP wants to set the option in his Admin Panel so it's displayed to users of the site.